# How to handle errors in Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am pretty new to Ramda and functional programming and trying to rewrite a script with Ramda but am unsure of how to handle errors with Ramda in a clean way. 
This is what I have, does anyone have any pointers with how to rewrite this in a functional way using Ramda?

```
const targetColumnIndexes = targetColumns.map(h => {
    if (header.indexOf(h) == -1) {
      throw new Error(`Target Column Name not found in CSV header column: ${h}`)
    }
    return header.indexOf(h)
  })
```

For reference, these are the values of `header` and `targetColumns`

```
const header = [ 'CurrencyCode', 'Name', 'CountryCode' ]
const targetColumns = [ 'CurrencyCode', 'Name' ]
```

So I need to:

- map over targetColumns
- return the indexOf the targetColumn from header
- throw an error if the index is `-1`

Comment: In functional programming where you compose functions together, you generally don't want to interrupt the flow of data by throwing errors. I think things like Monads can help you here. While this is definitely a subject worth exploring in more depth, you should also ask yourself whether throwing an error in this specific case is actually useful? Can't a default header work for example? Personally I'd throw an error only when my program has encountered a case that is impossible to recover from.

Comment: Thanks custom, this is for a node script whereby the user provides target column names from a csv file, and then maps these names to new names required by the program. If the provided column name is not found in the csv file, the program needs to alert the user, and can't run.

Comment: Usually you'd use continuation passing style or a monad with short circuit capability. I don't know though, if Ramda offers or facilitates these means.

Comment: Very broad question. Look at folktale's [data.either](https://github.com/folktale/data.either) module for guidance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As customcommander says, there is a good reason that this style of throwing exceptions is not made easy by functional programming: it's much harder to reason about.

> "What does you function return?"
>
> "A number."
>
> "Always?"
>
> "Yes, ... well unless it throws an exception."
>
> "Then what does it return?"
>
> "Well it doesn't."
>
> "So it returns a number or nothing at all?"
>
> "I guess so."
>
> "Hmmm."

One of the most common operations in functional programming is composing two functions.  But that only works if the output of one function match the input of its successor.  This is difficult if the first one might throw an exception.

To deal with this the FP world uses types that capture the notions of failure.  You may have seen talk of the `Maybe` type, which handles values that might be `null`.  Another common one is `Either` (sometimes `Result`), which has two subtypes, for the error case and the success one (respectively `Left` and `Right` for `Either` or `Error` and `Ok` for `Result`.) In these types, the first error found is captured and passed down the line to whoever needs it, while the success case continues to process.  (There are also `Validation` types that capture a list of errors.)

There are many implementations of these types.  See the [fantasy-land list](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land/blob/master/implementations.md) for some suggestions.

Ramda used to have its own set of these types, but has backed away from maintaining it.  Folktale and Sanctuary are the ones we often recommend for this.  But even Ramda's old implementation should do.  This version uses [Folktale's `data.either`](https://github.com/folktale/data.either) as it's one I know better, but later versions of Folktale replace this with a `Result`.

The following code block shows how I might use `Either`s to handle this notion of failure, especially how we can use [`R.sequence`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sequence) to convert an array of `Eithers` into an `Either` holding an array.  If the input includes any `Left`s, the output is just a `Left`.  If it's all `Right`s, then the output is a `Right` containing an array of their values.  With this we can convert all our column names into `Either`s that capture the value or the error, but then combine them into a single result.

The thing to note is that there are no exceptions thrown here.  Our functions will compose properly.  The notion of failure is encapsulated in the type.

```js
const header = [ 'CurrencyCode', 'Name', 'CountryCode' ]

const getIndices = (header) => (targetColumns) => 
  map((h, idx = header.indexOf(h)) => idx > -1
    ? Right(idx)
    : Left(`Target Column Name not found in CSV header column: ${h}`)
  )(targetColumns)

const getTargetIndices = getIndices(header)

// ----------

const goodIndices = getTargetIndices(['CurrencyCode', 'Name'])

console.log('============================================')
console.log(map(i => i.toString(), goodIndices))  //~> [Right(0), Right(1)]
console.log(map(i => i.isLeft, goodIndices))      //~> [false, false]
console.log(map(i => i.isRight, goodIndices))     //~> [true, true]
console.log(map(i => i.value, goodIndices))       //~> [0, 1]

console.log('--------------------------------------------')

const allGoods = sequence(of, goodIndices)

console.log(allGoods.toString())                  //~> Right([0, 1])
console.log(allGoods.isLeft)                      //~> false
console.log(allGoods.isRight)                     //~> true
console.log(allGoods.value)                       //~> [0, 1]

console.log('============================================')

//----------

const badIndices = getTargetIndices(['CurrencyCode', 'Name', 'FooBar'])

console.log('============================================')
console.log(map(i => i.toString(), badIndices))   //~> [Right(0), Right(1), Left('Target Column Name not found in CSV header column: FooBar')
console.log(map(i => i.isLeft, badIndices))       //~> [false, false, true]
console.log(map(i => i.isRight, badIndices))      //~> [true, true, false]
console.log(map(i => i.value, badIndices))        //~> [0, 1, 'Target Column Name not found in CSV header column: FooBar']


console.log('--------------------------------------------')

const allBads = sequence(of, badIndices)          
console.log(allBads.toString())                   //~> Left('Target Column Name not found in CSV header column: FooBar')
console.log(allBads.isLeft)                       //~> true
console.log(allBads.isRight)                      //~> false
console.log(allBads.value)                        //~> 'Target Column Name not found in CSV header column: FooBar'
console.log('============================================')
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {height: 100% !important}
```

```html
<script src="//bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script>
<!--script src="//bundle.run/ramda-fantasy@0.8.0"></script-->
<script src="//bundle.run/data.either@1.5.2"></script>
<script>
const {map, includes, sequence} = ramda
const Either = data_either;
const {Left, Right, of} = Either
</script>
```

The main point to me is that values such as `goodIndices` and `badIndices` are useful on their own.  If we want to do more processing with them, we can simply `map` over them.  Note for instance that

```
map(n => n * n, Right(5))     //=> Right(25)
map(n => n * n, Left('oops')) //=> Left('oops'))
```

So our errors are left alone and our successes are processed further.

```
map(map(n => n + 1), badIndices) 
//=> [Right(1), Right(2), Left('Target Column Name not found in CSV header column: FooBar')]
```

And this is what these types are all about.

Comment: Oops, you missed a `)` after `Left('oops')`. Great answer, Scott :D

Comment: @user633183: Oops!  I also used "predecessor" when I meant "successor".  Both fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Scott, this is great, going to take me a little while to wrap my head all around this, but this is just the thing I was looking for - thank you :)

Comment: Ok, twice in an evening, on two different post, you shed light on some useful concepts. And I spend the day reading blog posts about similar things. You should write one :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to offer a dissenting opinion: `Either` is a good solution for pounding square pegs through a static type system's round holes. It's a lot of cognitive overhead for less benefit in JavaScript (lack of correctness guarantees).

If the code in question needs to be fast (as proven by profiling and documented performance budget), you should be writing it in an imperative style.

If it doesn't need to be fast (or it's fast enough when implementing the following), then you can just check that the thing you're iterating is a proper subset (or exact match for) of the CSV headers:

```
// We'll assume sorted data. You can check for array equality in other ways,
// but for arrays of primitives this will work.
if (`${header}` !== `${targetColumns}`) throw new Error('blah blah');
```

This gives a clean separation of concerns from checking if the data is valid and doing the desired transform.

If all you're worried about is the length, then just check that, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If throwing exceptions defies functional programming, I guess that makes me an anarchist. Here is how you can write your function in a functional way

```js
const { map, switchCase } = require('rubico')

const header = ['CurrencyCode', 'Name', 'CountryCode']

const ifHeaderDoesNotExist = h => header.indexOf(h) === -1

const getHeaderIndex = h => header.indexOf(h)

const throwHeaderNotFound = h => {
  throw new Error(`Target Column Name not found in CSV header column: ${h}`)
}

const getTargetColumnIndex = switchCase([
  ifHeaderDoesNotExist, throwHeaderNotFound,
  getHeaderIndex,
])

const main = () => {
  const targetColumns = ['CurrencyCode', 'Name']
  const targetColumnIndexes = map(getTargetColumnIndex)(targetColumns)
  console.log(targetColumnIndexes) // => [0, 1]
}

main()
```

map is like ramda's map

you can think of the above switchCase as

```js
const getTargetColumnIndex = x =>
  ifHeaderDoesNotExist(x) ? throwHeaderNotFound(x) : getHeaderIndex(x)
```